# IBM Wepshere JET Transformation pageLayout Unavailable

Tags: java, websphere-commerce

This is my first question and I am really sorry if I made any mistakes.

So, I've been trying to follow the instruction on the following page http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZLC2_7.0.0/com.ibm.commerce.pagecomposerframework.doc/tasks/tpzwidgetcreatesrccd.htm?lang=en to make a Websphere Widget. However, I'm stucked at step 4e, which says "In the Transformation section, select com.ibm.commerce.toolkit.internal.pattern.pageLayout for the value of the ID field."

I'm stucked at that step because I don't have that particular ID in my JET Transformation. These are the only available selections that I have:

1. com.ibm.commerce.toolkit.internal.pattern.componentprojects
2. com.ibm.commerce.toolkit.internal.pattern.rest
3. com.ibm.xtools.jet2.newproject
4. com.ibm.xtools.jet2.transforms.projectupdater
5. org.eclipse.jet.transforms.taglibdoc

My IBM Rational Application Developer version is 8.0.4.2 iFix1 in IBM WebSphere Commerce Server 7.0.

Is there anything I need to do first so I can have the com.ibm.commerce.toolkit.internal.pattern.pageLayout ID to show up in my JET Transformation? Thank you very much in advance for all the helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's seems that this feature is available only in FEP7+. So you need to find `com.ibm.commerce.toolkit.internal.pattern.pageLayout` in JET ID.